# File not being released after upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Using Asp.Net MVC, I'm uploading a zip file and extracting it using the following method, and there seems to be a process still attached to it, as I cannot delete it in Windows Explorer after processing.

Here's the controller post:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ImportZip(HttpPostedFileBase zip)
{
    try
    {
        if (zip == null)
            throw new Exception("Please select a file to import");

        var result = new ContentManagementImporter(EducorDbRepo).ImportZipFile(zip);

        ViewData[ViewDataKeys.SuccessMessage] = result;
        return View("Import");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SetViewError(ex);
        return View("Import");
    }
}
```

And here's the method that process the uploaded file:

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> UnzipFiles(HttpPostedFileBase zipFile)
{
    var files = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(zipFile.InputStream))
    {
        foreach (var file in archive.Entries)
        {
            if (file == null)
                continue;

            using (var stream = file.Open())
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var markup = reader.ReadToEnd();
                files.Add(file.Name, markup);
            }
        }
    }

    zipFile.InputStream.Close();

    return files;
}
```

Can you see where in the code I'm failing to close something that needs to be closed, or is there another reason?

Comment: A `using` around `zipFile.InputStream` could help.

Comment: I thought a Close() call would be sufficient for that, although it might not help with error conditions

Comment: What does `ImportZipFile` do?

Comment: I added a `using` and it made no difference.  Technically what happens is I shift-delete the file in Windows Explorer, and when I refresh, the file reappears and opening it gives me a denied access message.  Rebooting my PC allows me to delete, so I assume there's a process lock on the file.

Comment: sab669, nothing exciting, not worth posting. It passes the zip file to the method I posted.

Comment: mjwills, I think you're on the money. Experiencing this with Firefox, can't replicate in Chrome or Edge. Can you post as an answer?  Perhaps this is related: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1123448

Comment: If you call `zipFile.InputStream.Dispose();` before `zipFile.InputStream.Close();` does that work? I suppose if the `using` statement didn't then this wouldn't. I'm looking over how my software handles file uploads and we have an `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>` property . We use a `foreach` to iterate over it but the only actual manipulation of that object we call is `myObj.SaveAs("")`, `myObj.InputStream.Dispose()`, `myObj.InputStream.Close()`, `myObj.InputStream.Flush()`

Comment: You make a good point, but when I switched to a `using` structure, it made no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server behaviour can't lock files on the client. As such, I am 90% sure any locking you are seeing is caused by the browser itself (and thus outside your control).

You may want to consider trying an alternate browser and seeing what happens.

Comment: Confirmed this behaviour occurs in Firefox but not in Chrome or Edge

Comment: How could the browser lock the file on the server, though? I mean, if other browsers work for OP then you must be on the right track clearly. I just don't understand.

Comment: The browser is locking a file on the client, not the server. It isn't locking the file on the server. There isn't a file on the server at all (well, not according to the source code above). It is locking a file on the client. I suspect he is running the web server on his own machine - in which case the client and the server are the same machine - which muddied the issue for him.

Comment: Yep, was running as localhost